# SVN 405 Error: Could not fetch resource information

Tags: apache, svn, commit, svn-server

Dear Stackoverflow Community!
Recently my svn server broke, and I tried nearly everything but I can't get it to work again.

OS: Raspbian

What I did:
installing packages:

```
apt-get install subversion libapache2-svn apache2 mysql-server
```

Enabeling dav_svn: `a2enmod dav_svn`

Creating repositories:

```
$ mkdir -p /opt/svn/project1
$ mkdir -p /opt/svn/project2
```

Adding them:

```
$ svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs /opt/svn/project1
$ svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs /opt/svn/project2`
```

Setting the owner:

```
$ chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/svn
```

Created users:

```
$ sudo htpasswd /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd weini
```

Created repository files:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/projet1/trunk
mkdir -p /tmp/projet1/branches
mkdir -p /tmp/projet1/tags
mkdir -p /tmp/projet2/trunk
mkdir -p /tmp/projet2/branches
mkdir -p /tmp/projet2/tags
```

Created `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf` file:

```
<Location /svn/>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /opt/svn/
        SVNListParentPath On
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion Repository"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
        Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Imported them: Note accessing the repository via `http://` does not work; via `file://` works

```
Error: svn import /tmp/project1 http://localhost/svn/project1 -m "initialer Import" 
Error: svn import /tmp/project2 http://localhost/svn/project2 -m "initialer Import" 
Works: svn import /tmp/project1 file://opt/svn/project1 -m "initialer Import" 
Works: svn import /tmp/project2 file://opt/svn/project2 -m "initialer Import"`
```

Everything else are default settings!

Errormessage:

```
RA layer request failed
svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://server.weini.at/svn/project1'
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed)  in response to OPTIONS request for 'http://server.weini.at/svn/project1
```

Syslog:

```
no errors
```

Apache2/error.log:

```
[Wed Apr 09 22:29:29 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.1] Could not fetch resource  information.  [-2, #0]
[Wed Apr 09 22:29:29 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.1] (2)No such file or directory:   The URI does not contain the name of a repository.  [405, #190001]
```

When i try to access the repositories via my webbrowser everything works normal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNKzw.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to comment out this line:

```
SVNListParentPath On
```

-->

```
#SVNListParentPath On
```

(switching to off should also work).

And restart your apache.

There seems to be an issue with ParentPath since the last apache upgrades.

Thanks to this (german) post:
http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/problem-mit-svn-server-nach-apache-update/#post-6513997

The problem is, after this setup, the listing of your parent path in browser is not possible... . So for me this is not a final solution.

Cheers,
markus

Answer (score 0):

A few things I noticed:

Creating repositories:

```
$ mkdir -p /opt/svn/project1
$ mkdir -p /opt/svn/project2
```

Adding them:

```
$ svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs /opt/svn/project1
$ svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs /opt/svn/project2
```

Your repo directories are created when you create the repo:

```
$ mkdir -p /opt/svn
$ svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs /opt/svn/project1
$ svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs /opt/svn/project2
```

You also had this:

Created repository files:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/projet1/trunk
mkdir -p /tmp/projet1/branches
mkdir -p /tmp/projet1/tags
mkdir -p /tmp/projet2/trunk
mkdir -p /tmp/projet2/branches
mkdir -p /tmp/projet2/tags
```

You're suppose to use `svn mkdir` to make these directories. You're just creating a bunch of directories that have nothing to do with your project:

```
$ svn co http://localhost/svn/project1
$ cd project1
$ svn mkdir trunk branches tags
$ svn commit
```

Or...

```
$ REPO=http://localhost/svn/project2
$ svn mkdir $REPO/trunk $REPO/branches $REPO/tags
```

The fact that `file://` works and `http://` means you have problems with Apache. Did you restart Apache once you changed the configuration?

```
$ /etc/init.d/httpd graceful   # Restarts gracefully...
```

Comment: Thanks for the infos but it still get the 405 error.
Thats what i did after the restart: http://pastebin.com/yMw8czwE

Comment: One more thing: Looking at my httpd configuration, you may need to remove that final slash from `SVNParentPath /opt/svn/` to make it `SVNParentPath /opt/svn`. Restart Apache, and see if that does it. Otherwise, something is going on with the Subversion DAV setup.

Comment: Hmmm I removed the / from `SVNParentPath /opt/svn/` and restarted the apache2 server `service apache2 restart`.
I tried to check out my project with `svn co http://localhost/svn/project1` and i still get the same error as on my first post.

Comment: Also what to mention is that this is a complete clean version of the raspdebian, which means I just have the apache2 server and the svn package running.

Comment: It's hard to analyze the situation from a distance. These are native packages which means they were all compiled together. so svn should work. Everything you stated looks right. You don't have `AuthzSVNAccessFile` defined, but I don't believe that's needed. Can you use `svnserve`. You can do multiple repos with `svnserve` by starting `svnserve` in the parent directory of the repos. However, you need to make sure port 3690 open and unblocked.

Comment: So, `SVNListParentPath` doesn't work in the latest versions of Apache? As I said, it looked like you had everything setup correctly. I had SVNListParentPath in ours, but I guess it isn't the latest Apache version.