# SVN Unexpected HTTP status 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: linux, svn, raspberry-pi, webdav, svn-server

I have installed svnserver on my RaspberryPI a year ago...

Since i've recently updated my RaspberryPI with `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` i cannot do any operation on my repos anymore. It shows the following errors when i try to `checkout`, `update`:

```
Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL http://myurl.com/svn/my-repo-name   
Error: Unexpected HTTP status 405 'Method Not Allowed' on '/svn/my-repo-name'  
Error: Additional errors:
Error: The URI does not contain the name of a repository.
```

I have checked my svn configuration files, but they didn't changed after the update.
Could someone help me? I've no idea whats going on :S

Thanks in advice

Comment: What do your apt-logs say about what got updated, installed, and possibly removed? And what does your webserver say in its error logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There seems to be an issue with ParentPath since the last apache
>   upgrades.

Solved it commenting out the following line:

```
#SVNListParentPath On
```

Finally restart your Apache.

Source: [SVN 405 Error: Could not fetch resource information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973591/svn-405-error-could-not-fetch-resource-information)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem because I was trying to checkout the repository from following path:

**http**://192.168.1.70/xyz/abc

whereas the correct way of doing that was:

**svn**://192.168.1.70/xyz/abc